# Getting Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587 in ubuntu terminal while sending email using ssmtp

Tags: xubuntu, email

```
#PFB my configuration

root=test@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

AuthUser=test@gmail.com
AuthPass=*****
UseTLS=YES
UeSTARTTLS=
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
hostname=test@gmail.com
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Comment: msmtp might be a better choice: http://www.andrews-corner.org/linux/mutt.html#sending